# Picard Iteration of $Y_n(t) = y_0 + c \int_{t_o}^t s Y_{n-1}(s) \, ds$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $(t_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $Y_0(t) = y_0$, $$Y_n(t) = y_0 + c \int_{t_o}^t s Y_{n-1}(s) \, ds.$$ I need to compute $Y_n(t)$ and $Y(t) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Y_n(t).$

I know that I need to compute $Y_n(t)$ by induction but I am getting stuck on coming up with a general forumla for $Y_n(t)$. So far I have that $$Y_1(t) = y_0 \left( 1+c \frac{t^2-t_o^2}{2} \right)$$ and $$Y_2(t) = y_0 \left( 1+c \frac{t^2-t_0^2}{2} - c \frac{(t^2-t_0^2)t_0^2}{4} + c^2 \frac{t^4-t_0^4}{8} \right).$$
I can compute the expression for $Y_3(t)$, and so on, but I'm not seeing a general forumla for $Y_n(t)$ so that I can use it to do the proof by induction.

Comment: I like that you're expanding this in powers of $c$, but perhaps keeping the integral expressions around (instead of fully evaluating) will prove useful?

Comment: are you sure with your $$Y_2(t)$$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula for $Y_1(t)$,

$Y_1(t) = y_0 \left( 1+c \dfrac{t^2-t_o^2}{2} \right) \tag 1$

is wrong.  The $s$ doesn't belong in the integrand.  With

$Y_1(t) = y_0 + c \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t Y_0(s) \; ds, \tag 2$

and

$Y_0(t) = y_0, \tag{3}$

the correct $Y_1(t)$ is given by

.$Y_1(t) = y_0 + cy_0( t - t_0) = y_0(1 + c(t - t_0)); \tag 4$

from this, we obtain

$Y_2(t) = y_0 + \displaystyle c \int_{t_0}^t Y_1(s) = 
y_0 + y_0 c (t - t_0) + \dfrac{1}{2} y_0 c^2 (t - t_0)^2; \tag 5$

a pattern begins to energe; indeed we have

$Y_3(t) = y_0 + y_0 c (t - t_0) + \dfrac{1}{2} y_0 c^2 (t - t_0)^2 + \dfrac{1}{6} y_0 c^3(t - t_0)^3; \tag 6$

at this point, since it is past my bedtime, I leave it to the reader to show inductively that

$Y_n(t) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n  \dfrac{1}{i!} y_0 c^i (t - t_0)^i, \tag 7$

which converges to

$Y(t) = y_0 e^{c(t - t_0)}; \tag 8$

the proofs of convergence are easy, so I leave them to my audience as well, and bid you good night.

Comment: $$
\int\limits_{t_0}^t s \; ds = \frac{1}{2} s^2 \Big|_{t_0}^t =\frac{1}{2} \big( t^2 - t_0^2 \big)
$$

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by $s$ shouldn’t be in the integrand. It’s in the integrand in the problem that I was given. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Usually Picard iteration is defined as $Y_n(t) = y_0 + \int_{t_0}^t Y_n(s) \; ds$ without the additional factor of $s$ in the integrand.  So I was going with that.